# Oracle between dates sysdate range vs literal date range

Tags: oracle, range, literals, between, sysdate

Here is the situation :

```
select sysdate from dual ;

>  30-APR-19

SELECT
  count(*)
FROM 
  event_log
WHERE
  edate between to_date('04232019', 'MMDDYYYY') and to_date('04292019', 'MMDDYYYY') ;

> 1156

SELECT
  count(*)
FROM 
  event_log
WHERE
  edate between (sysdate-7) and (sysdate-1) ;

> 1276
```

This is an event log, rows are date-tagged (row counts for previous days are static).

My question - why aren't the counts the same?  What am i missing?  Is there some semantic difference between the two ranges?

Comment: Is “edate” a DATETIME field? That would clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SYSDATE` is a function that returns both date and time component. If you don't `TRUNC`ate it, you'd get both:

```
SQL> select sysdate,
  2         sysdate - 7 prev_week,
  3         sysdate - 1 yesterday
  4  from dual;

SYSDATE             PREV_WEEK           YESTERDAY
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
30.04.2019 23:13:14 23.04.2019 23:13:14 29.04.2019 23:13:14

SQL>
```

If you `TRUNC`ate it, you'd get the midnight:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) today,
  2         trunc(sysdate - 7) prev_week,
  3         trunc(sysdate - 1) yesterday
  4  from dual;

TODAY               PREV_WEEK           YESTERDAY
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
30.04.2019 00:00:00 23.04.2019 00:00:00 29.04.2019 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Which means that your last condition should, probably, be

```
where edate between trunc(sysdate-7) and trunc(sysdate-1) ;
```

Comment: perfect.  that clears the problem, Littlefoot. danke shoen !

Comment: Bitte, I'm glad if it helped.